# Search by data from the input file?

Tags: search, splunk

Instead of very long search query such as:

```
Foo OR Bar OR Buzz OR 1.2.3 OR ...
```

I'd like to load the list of search strings/queries from the input file. The format of the input file could be either plain text file where each string is separated by the new line character (something similar to `grep -f` shell command when filtering the logs), in CSV format (`Foo,Bar,Buzz,1.2.3`), text file with a long query, or ability to create such data from the UI.

Ideally this input data should be managed or editable, so it can be re-used after modification.

How this can be achieved in Splunk?

I'm using Splunk Version: 7.0.2.

Comment: A quick Google [suggests this is how to do it](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/2378/running-a-saved-search-from-the-command-line-interface-cli.html).

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you, unfortunately I don't have direct access to CLI. But I can try to ask a person to try who does.